# No sound from microphone over Remote Desktop (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services

I'm trying to allow users to properly use video/voice chat software (like Teams) on our Remote Desktop server. Sound playback works fine, but I've been unable to get sound input (microphone input) through to the server.

The sound control panel on the remote server shows my input device as "Remote Audio", but shows no incoming signal when tested. On the local computer, the sound control panel does show a signal, so the mic is working locally, just not over RDP.

Remote server is running Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. Local clients are running Windows 10 or 11.

I have done some research on this issue, here's everything I've already tried:

- In the Remote Desktop client, setting `Local Resources > Remote audio > Remote audio recording` to `Record from this computer`.
- Ensure that both the `Windows Audio` and `Windows Audio Endpoint Builder` services are running on both the client and server machines.
- Test that the microphone is working locally (as mentioned above).
- On the remote server, edited group policy located in `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection`. I set `Allow audio and video playback redirection` and `Allow audio recording redirection` to `Enabled`. All other policy options in that folder remain `Not configured`.
- Testing a second client machine.
- Testing a second user account on the remote server.

None of the above fixed the problem for me. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you're connected within your RDP Session, did you check within :
Settings > Privacy , then check within Microphone if the wanted apps are ticked or not.

Comment: Good suggestion. I did not check there. Unfortunately I don't see anything helpful. On the remote server, even Windows itself seems to be getting no mic input (seen via the Control Panel). On the local machine (while RD is connected), nothing with a name similar to "Remote Desktop" appears in either the "apps" or "desktop apps" sections of the microphone privacy settings page.

Comment: Crap... Another idea : if you go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ Terminal Server \ WinStations \ RDP-TCP, what's the value of fDisableAudioCapture ? (enabled value : 0, disabled value : 1)

Comment: The value of fDisableAudioCapture is 0 on both server and client.